# Synch Two SQLITE tables from different Databases iphone ios

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

what would be the best way to synch two exact tables from two different databases in SQLITE?  Right now we are simply deleting rows in one table and inserting them, but this soon will not be efficient enough due to table size.  There are some advanced ways in larger database engines, but this is SQLITE on IOS.

databasesource tablea 
databasetarget tableb

where tablea and tableb are the same schema.

1) Delete rows in target database, insert rows from source database

.....
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing row by row insert from one table to another after clearing target.